# Help fix alignment

Tags: table-of-contents, alignment

I was trying to add reference and appendices into TOC with the following command lines

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{References}}
\bibliography{References}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{APPENDICES}}
\appendix
\section*{APPENDICES}
```

However, they added to the TOC in one single line, with text overlay together. I'm wondering how to make References and APPENDICES align properly (line after line) on TOC?

Here is the error picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using the `article` document class that does not define `chapter`s. As such, the setting of chapters within the ToC is not well-defined. Rather set your bibliography and appendices using `section`s, not `chapter`s:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{<title>}
```

Secondly, avoid setting ToC elements with their formatting explicitly. There are packages like [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) that can manage this for you at the document level.

Comment: it works perfectly after replacing {chapter} with {section}. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @ysunny: Consider accepting this answer then. See [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)